# Writing own shell - code hangs when handling certain pipes - in C

Tags: c, linux, redirect, pipe, fork

I'm currently writing my own shell as a project for a class, and have everything virtually working. My problem is with my pipes, sometimes they work, and sometimes, they just hang until I interrupt them. I've done research on this, and it seems that the function that is getting it's stdin written to isn't receiving an EOF from the first process; usually as I've learned the problem is that the pipe isn't being closed, but this isn't the case (to my knowledge) with my code.

All redirection works and any variation thereof:

- `ls -l > file1`
- `wc < file1 > file2`

The following piped commands work:

- `w | head -n 4`
- `w | head -n 4 > file1`

This doesn't work: `ls | grep file1` it shows the correct output and never ends unless an interrupt signal is sent to it by the user. `ls | grep file1 > file2` also does not work. It hangs without showing output, creates the file2, but never writes to it.

Anyway, I hope there's something I'm missing that someone else can notice; I've been at this for a while. Let me know if there's anymore code I can provide. The code I've posted below is the main file, nothing removed.

```
/*
 * This code implemenFts a simple shell program
 * At this time it supports just simple commands with 
 * any number of args.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "input.h"
#include "myShell.h"
#include "BackgroundStack.h"

/*
 * The main shell function
 */ 
main() {
    char *buff[20];
    char *inputString;

    BackgroundStack *bgStack = malloc(sizeof(BackgroundStack));
    initBgStack(bgStack);

    struct sigaction new_act;
    new_act.sa_handler = sigIntHandler;
    sigemptyset ( &new_act.sa_mask );
    new_act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &new_act, NULL);

    // Loop forever
    while(1) {
        const char *chPath;

        doneBgProcesses(bgStack);

        // Print out the prompt and get the input
        printPrompt();

        inputString = get_my_args(buff);
        if (buff[0] == NULL) continue;

        if (buff[0][0] == '#') continue;

        switch (getBuiltInCommand(buff[0])) {
            case EXIT:
                exit(0);
                break;
            case CD:
                chPath = (buff[1]==NULL) ? getenv("HOME") : buff[1];
                if (chdir(chPath) < 0) {
                    perror(": cd");
                }
                break;
            default:
                do_command(buff, bgStack);
        }

        //free up the malloced memory
        free(inputString);
    }// end of while(1)
}

static void sigIntHandler (int signum) {}

/* 
 * Do the command
 */
int do_command(char **args, BackgroundStack *bgStack) {
    int status, statusb;  
    pid_t child_id, childb_id;
    char **argsb;
    int pipes[2];

    int isBgd = isBackgrounded(args);
    int hasPipe = hasAPipe(args);

    if (isBgd) removeBackgroundCommand(args);
    if (hasPipe) {
        int cmdBi = getSecondCommandIndex(args);
        args[cmdBi-1] = NULL;
        argsb = &args[cmdBi];
        pipe(pipes);
    }

    // Fork the child and check for errors in fork()
    if((child_id = fork()) == -1) {
        switch(errno) {
            case EAGAIN:
                perror("Error EAGAIN: ");
                return;
            case ENOMEM:
                perror("Error ENOMEM: ");
                return;
        }
    }

    if (hasPipe && child_id != 0) {
        childb_id = fork();
        if(childb_id == -1) {
            switch(errno) {
                case EAGAIN:
                    perror("Error EAGAIN: ");
                    return;
                case ENOMEM:
                    perror("Error ENOMEM: ");
                    return;
            }
        }
    }

    if(child_id == 0 || (childb_id == 0 && hasPipe)) {
        if (child_id != 0 && hasPipe) args = argsb;
        if (child_id == 0 && isBgd) {
            struct sigaction new_act;
            new_act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
            sigaction(SIGINT, &new_act, 0);
        }

        if (child_id == 0 && hasPipe) {
            if (dup2(pipes[1], 1) != 1) fatalPerror(": Pipe Redirection Output Error");
            close(pipes[0]);
            close(pipes[1]);
        }
        if (child_id != 0 && hasPipe) {
            if (dup2(pipes[0], 0) != 0) fatalPerror(": Pipe Redirection Input Error");
            close(pipes[0]);
            close(pipes[1]);
            waitpid(child_id, NULL, 0);
        }

        if ((child_id != 0 && hasPipe) || !hasPipe) {
            if (hasAReOut(args)) {
                char outFile[100];
                getOutFile(args, outFile);

                int reOutFile = open(outFile, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
                if (reOutFile<0) fatalPerror(": Redirection Output Error");

                if (dup2(reOutFile,1) != 1) fatalPerror(": Redirection Output Error");
                close(reOutFile);
            }
        }

        if ( (child_id == 0 && hasPipe) || !hasPipe) {
            if (hasAReIn(args)) {
                char inFle[100];
                getInFile(args, inFle);

                int reInFile = open(inFle, O_RDWR);
                if (reInFile<0) fatalPerror(": Redirection Input Error");

                if (dup2(reInFile,0) != 0) fatalPerror(": Redirection Input Error");
                close(reInFile);
            } else if (isBgd && !hasPipe) {
                int bgReInFile = open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
                if (bgReInFile<0) fatalPerror(": /dev/null Redirection Input Error");

                if (dup2(bgReInFile,0) != 0) fatalPerror(": /dev/null Redirection Input Error");
                close(bgReInFile);
            }
        }

        // Execute the command
        execvp(args[0], args);
        perror(args[0]);

        exit(-1);
    }

    // Wait for the child process to complete, if necessary
    if (!isBgd) waitpid(child_id, &status, 0);
    else if (!hasPipe) {
        printf("Child %ld started\n", (long)child_id);
        BackgroundProcess *bgPrs = malloc(sizeof(BackgroundProcess)); 
        bgPrs->pid = child_id;
        bgPrs->exitStatus = -1;

        addProcessToBgStack(bgStack, bgPrs);
    }
    if (hasPipe) waitpid(childb_id, &statusb, 0);
    if ( WIFSIGNALED(status) && !isBgd )    printf("Child %ld terminated due to signal %d\n", (long)child_id, WTERMSIG(status) );
    if ( hasPipe && WIFSIGNALED(statusb) ) printf("Child %ld terminated due to signal %d\n", (long)childb_id, WTERMSIG(status) );

} // end of do_command
```

Comment: If anyone wants to see the working code this is what I have: http://pastebin.com/VevMrng9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second child should *not* wait for the first child to exit - it should just start running straight away (it will block until some output is produced on the pipe by the first child), so remove that `waitpid()` executed by `childb`.  Instead, the parent process should wait for both child processes (or perhaps just the second one).  (Indeed, as noted by JeremyP, this `waitpid()` call is failing anyway, since `childb` is not the parent of `child`).

Your problem, though, is that the parent process is mainintaining open file descriptors to the pipe.  Right before the comment `// Wait for the child process to complete, if necessary`, the parent process should close its pipe file descriptors:

```
close(pipes[0]);
close(pipes[1]);
```

The open file descriptor in the parent means that the child `grep` process never sees EOF, so it doesn't exit.

Comment: Thank you, as you suggested, I closed the pipes (if the command included a pipe) before the parent waited for the it's children processes; it worked beautifully. I neglected to remember that the pipe was open in three different places.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer but I have spotted one issue.

You'll agree that the condition for

```
if(child_id == 0 || (childb_id == 0 && hasPipe))
```

is true only for the two child processes, but inside the if statement block you have this:

```
    if (child_id != 0 && hasPipe) {
        if (dup2(pipes[0], 0) != 0) fatalPerror(": Pipe Redirection Input Error");
        close(pipes[0]);
        close(pipes[1]);
        waitpid(child_id, NULL, 0);
    }
```

The `waitpid()` call is incorrect because it is called from the second child to wait for the first child.  It's probably failing with `ECHILD` because the first child is not a child of the second child.

As for your real problem, I suspect it has to do with the fact that the `grep` command will not terminate until its input is closed.  There might be some deadlock condition going on that stops that from happening.  You need to run this in a debugger or put some logging in to see where the parent process is hanging.

**Edit**

caf's answer tells us everything.

I was assuming that the input to grep was being closed because ls will close its output when it terminates, but of course, the parent process also has grep's input file descriptor open.  The version using `head` works properly because `head -n 4` terminates after four lines regardless of whether its input file descriptor is closed or not.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why I felt it was necessary for the second child to wait for the first one, I guess it was just a crazy act of me trying to fix the program. I went ahead and removed it.